# Interpreting valgrind output of R script

Tags: c++, r, valgrind, rcpp

I have a R script that throws a segfault error. The R script uses a package "RSofia" that internally calls a C++ program using Rcpp package which I believe is causing the issue.

Please refer to the link for the question I posted on the same: [RSofia Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500363/svm-using-rsofia-crashes-r)

I am trying to debug and identify what is causing the issue using valgrind as follows:

```
R -d "valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes" -f svm.r
```

This throws the following output:

```
==11235== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11235== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11235== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11235== Command: /usr/lib64/R/bin/exec/R -f svm.r
==11235== 

vex: priv/main_main.c:319 (LibVEX_Translate): Assertion `are_valid_hwcaps(VexArchAMD64, vta->archinfo_host.hwcaps)' failed.
vex storage: T total 0 bytes allocated
vex storage: P total 0 bytes allocated

valgrind: the 'impossible' happened:
  LibVEX called failure_exit().
==11235==    at 0x38031DA7: report_and_quit (m_libcassert.c:235)
==11235==    by 0x38031E0E: panic (m_libcassert.c:319)
==11235==    by 0x38031E68: vgPlain_core_panic_at (m_libcassert.c:324)
==11235==    by 0x38031E7A: vgPlain_core_panic (m_libcassert.c:329)
==11235==    by 0x3804D162: failure_exit (m_translate.c:708)
==11235==    by 0x380D4C38: vex_assert_fail (main_util.c:219)
==11235==    by 0x380D3009: LibVEX_Translate (main_main.c:319)
==11235==    by 0x3804AACE: vgPlain_translate (m_translate.c:1559)
==11235==    by 0x38079D9F: vgPlain_scheduler (scheduler.c:991)
==11235==    by 0x380A6409: run_a_thread_NORETURN (syswrap-linux.c:103)

sched status:
running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable
==11235==    at 0x4000B00: ??? (in /lib64/ld-2.12.so)
==11235==    by 0x2: ???
==11235==    by 0x7FF00036E: ???
==11235==    by 0x7FF000386: ???
==11235==    by 0x7FF000389: ???
```

Can someone help with how to locate the error from this message and what could be a possible fix to this?

Comment: For segfaults, it's usually 'easier' to run under a debugger and then to navigate up / down the frame to see the call causing problems. There are [some hints](http://bioconductor.org/developers/how-to/c-debugging/).

Comment: Valgrind 3.8.1 is now quite old. So, the first thing to try is to upgrade to the new release (3.11.0), which a.o. will support newer processor/hwcaps and/or will have less bugs :)

Comment: I installed Valgrind through yum install. Not sure it it picks up the old version.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is using an `assert()` which, according to `Writing R Extension` one should not be using in the first place.

Now why the `assert()` evaluates the way it does and hence aborts is another matter.  But for that one would need a minimally reproducible example, plus some spare time and patience.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. From Kevin's answer in the following thread, it appears that the problem is with a different function SfSparseVector. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500363/svm-using-rsofia-crashes-r

Comment: Yes,  and your use of valgrind was never quite right to investigate a segfault.

Comment: Dirk...unfortunately I came across a few references which guided me in that direction. One of them is here: http://thomas-cokelaer.info/blog/2013/03/using-valgrind-to-debug-r-programs/

Comment: Do you believe things you read on the Internet? Wow.  The mind boggles.

Comment: I agree...looking at your answer above about assert() I realize I shouldn't believe everything :)

Comment: I'm not an asserter myself, but I do see in Writing R Extensions section 1.7: " The normal way to ensure that is to define the macro NDEBUG, and as from R 2.15.0 R CMD INSTALL does so as part of the compilation flags. If you wish to use assert during development. you can include -UNDEBUG in PKG_CPPFLAGS. Note that your own `src/Makefile' or makefiles in sub-directories may also need to define NDEBUG."

Comment: I always read that as suggesting a way to allow `assert()` for debug builds only.  Don't get me wrong: `assert()` is a fine tool, but CRAN does not want us to take the enveloping R instance down. And they are right.